# Create Task in Snowflake in IST timezone

Tags: cron, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The documentation says `USING CRON <expr> <time_zone>` but when I try to do something like `'USING CRON 20 01 * * * IST'` I'm getting an error that says
`Invalid schedule was specified. "IST" is not a recognized time zone. Please specify time zones accepted by the TIMEZONE parameter.`

Comment: What is confusing you about the error message?

Comment: how can I schedule with IST? I'm not sure what format to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'USING CRON 20 01 * * * Asia/Kolkata'` is the format you're looking for. This is how it's written according to [this page](https://iana.org/time-zones)